# Rutas en Angular 5

Tags: html, web, angular, typescript

Me podrías ayudar con lo siguiente?:

Tengo en Angular un sidebar que me redirige a una ruta **ADMIN**, esta ruta tiene una hija denominada **ESTUDIANTES**. Para cuando el usuario entre a la ruta **ADMIN**, eh definido que se cargue automáticamente una ruta hija, para que el usuario no caiga en un **empty state**

```
path: 'admin', component: DashAdminComponent, children: [
  { path: '', component: EstudiantesComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
   { path: 'estudiantes', component: EstudiantesComponent}
```

esto funciona correctamente, sin embargo, aunque eh definido el atributo **[routerLinkActive]="clase"**, el ancla no recibe la clase:

```
<li class="text-center" routerLinkActive="active">
                <a [routerLink]="['estudiantes']">
                    <i class="fa fa-user fa-lg f_1rem"></i>
                    <a class="pb-0 pt-2 pl-3 pl-lg-0">
                        Estudiantes
                    </a>
                </a>
</li>
```

Solo si doy click sobre al ancla el atributo **[routerLinkActive]** surge efecto, y me gustaria que se aplique junto con la redireccion automatica. Adjunto imagenes para ilustrar mejor.
Agradezo cualquier ayuda y segurencia.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No estás haciendo redirección automática, estas diciendo que si la ruta está vacía muestre el componente `EstudiantesComponent`. La redireccion se hace así:

```
path: 'admin', component: DashAdminComponent, children: [
  { path: '', redirecTo: 'estudiantes', pathMatch: 'full' },
   { path: 'estudiantes', component: EstudiantesComponent}
```